# Submit button not working when modal is opened

Tags: button, modal-dialog, submit, zurb-foundation

I have a Foundation modal that has a contact form and a submit button. The submit button works fine when I open the modal in the navigation.

I have another form on the main page of the site in a section called 'Wedding Date Availability'. When you type for example: 05-05-2016 it will tell you it's available and a button will say "book it now'. That button also initiates the Foundation modal contact form. But submit button stops working after that...any advice?

Comment: Forgot to add the link lol - here it is: http://www.overtheoceanfilms.com/index_2.php

Comment: I can see that an error appears after clicking the "book today" button: `foundation.min.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sticky_class' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. There was a include('header.php') in one of my pages that was making the submit button not work. It was strange. It's working now.